# VideoView Add a multiple videos and play

Tags: java, android, video, android-videoview

Lets pretend that a 5 videos in sdcard or internal storage.
now I already get the file path, my problem is how can i insert a multiple videos in VIDEO VIEW ?

**The next or previous button is not functioning**

here is my code

```
 public void getFile()
{

    urls = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("url_videoAll");
    keys = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("key_videoAll");

    for(int i = 0; i<urls.size();i++) {
        String FileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(urls.get(0), null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(urls.get(0)));
        String yourFilePath = getBaseContext().getFilesDir() + "/" + FileName;
        fileList.add(new File(yourFilePath));

    }
    playallvideo(fileList);
}
```

in this CODE ARE WORKING IN SINGLE VIDEO how about if i have 5 videos ?

```
private void playallvideo(final List<File> file)
    {
    mediaController = new MediaController(this);

    video.setMediaController(mediaController);
    video.setVideoPath(file.get(0).toString());
    video.start();

    mediaController.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            video.setMediaController(mediaController);
            video.setVideoPath(file.get(1).toString());
            video.requestFocus();
            video.start();
            // code for next
        }
    }, new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            video.setMediaController(mediaController);
            video.setVideoPath(file.get(1).toString());
            video.requestFocus();
            video.start();
            // code for previous
        }
    });
}
```

**I need this because I will use MediaController and press the next video**

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter and increment the value of it as soon as the first video has stopped playing. This can be achieved by using the `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener`.

Below worked for me:

```
private static int currentVideo = 0;
private List<String> fileData = new ArrayList<String>();

videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        if(!(currentPosition < fileData.size())) {
            return;
        }
        Uri nextUri = Uri.parse(fileData.get(currentPosition++));
        videoView.setVideoURI(nextUri);
        videoView.start();
        //to keep looping into the list, reset the counter to 0.
        //in case you need to stop playing after the list is completed remove the code.
        if(currentPosition == fileData.size()) {
            currentPosition = 0;
        }
    }
});
```

Though the post is too old to answer, the beginner developers who end up here will get as much help as I did.

Comment: setOnCompletionListener did not trigger, even with loop set to false